# HTML Entity Hex Character reference not working

Tags: javascript, java, html-entities

I am trying to escape and unescape html entities.
For Escaping, I have used to below code which work fine.

```
function reformat(string) {
var entityMap = {
    '&' : '&amp;',
    '<' : '&lt;',
    '>' : '&gt;',
    '"' : '&quot;',
    "'" : "'",
    '/' : '/',
    '`' : '&#x60;',
    '=' : '=',
    '■' : '&#x25a0;',
    '▲' : '&#x25b2;'
};

if (string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=■▲\/]/g,
            function fromEntityMap(s) {
                return entityMap[s];
            });
}
```

};

For Unescaping, I have tried using JSOUP Parser,

```
        Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        boolean strictMode = true;
        html = org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, strictMode);
```

HTMLUtils: org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils

```
html = HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(html);
```

Uebescape: org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscape

```
html = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(html);
```

Besides, I have tried using commons-lang and commons-text. Still, I get no luck to unescape these two characters only.

```
     '■' : '&#x25a0;',
    '▲' : '&#x25b2;',
```

Note: I am using HEX CHARACTER REFERENCE.

Comment: That's surprising. I mean, it's easy enough to work around with `replaceAll`, but still, it's surprising that you have to... Have you tried the decimal equivalents (`&#9632;` and `&#9650;`)? What versions of JSoup/HTMLUtils/HtmlEscape have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using decimal values too. @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have much hope that would work. :-)

Comment: Rather than getting them unescaped, I am getting values like &#x25a0; for box, and &#x25b2; for triangle. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Seriously? With JSoup? I find that very hard to believe. Again, what version?

Comment: I just used Jsoup v1.11.3 and had no problem. The result of `Jsoup.parse(html).text()` on `<p>Testing &#x25a0; and &#x25b2;</p>` was `Testing ■ and ▲` and the result of `org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true)` on it was `<p>Testing ■ and ▲</p>`. I should note that your code in the question doesn't do anything with the result of `Jsoup.parse(html).text()`, it just calls it and throws away the result...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used jsoup-1.6.0

Comment: Let me implement using Jsoup v1.11.3.

Comment: The method unescapeEntities(String, boolean) is undefined for the type Parser @T.J.Crowder. I am getting this error

Comment: Sounds like a classpath problem. It's definitely there in v1.11.3.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , what was import you used?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I used the code you showed (because I copied and pasted), which doesn't rely on an `import`: `org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true)`. But here's my complete test class: https://pastebin.com/L90iqFH9

Comment: org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true) comes from org.jsoup.parser.Parser. You have not imported the one.

Comment: I suggest you review what `import` does and what it's for ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)). `org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true)` doesn't require any imports at all, it's a fully-qualified class name. Doesn't matter what imports you have (unless you do something to change what `org` is, and...don't do that :-) ), `org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true)` will work the same regardless.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I got your point thanks.

Comment: But still, I am getting, The method unescapeEntities(String, boolean) is undefined for the type Parser. I have added the jar of JSOUP into my project even though.

Comment: I really hate to say it, but we're back where we were [when I posted this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636588/html-entity-hex-character-reference-not-working?noredirect=1#comment94135084_53636588). Sounds like a classpath problem. I hope you solve it!

Comment: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jsoup-1.11.3.jar" sourcepath="/tmp/decompiler/source/jsoup-1.11.3-sources.jar"/> this is how my classpath file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having conflict in classpath, there were two different version of JSOUP 1.6.0, and JSOUP 1.11.3. I just removed the jsoup1.6.0 and it all started to work.

> We dont have org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(html, true) method in Jsoup-1.6.0 version.